# Building XUL app a-la SongBird

Tags: macos, deployment, xul

I've started exploring XUL Runner as a potential tool for an upcoming app.

I can get some good examples running using the command line xulrunner-bin myapp.

How can compile it all in a native looking application, like SongBird does.

I understand SongBird packages the entire xul runtime with it, and I'm happy with that. I'm just wondering is there are any tool I can use to compile my xul project as a standalone app?

Any Mac and/or PC hint much appreciated!

EDIT: I guess what I'm looking for is a way to generate a Mac and/or PC XUL stub application (but not an installer). Is there something like that?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you interested in XUL runner?  Of all of the application frameworks I have worked with, it is the most complicated and worst documented.

Comment: @mikerobi. I like that it's cross platform. Also like that you can build an app really quickly using just html and JS if needed. I do agree, the doc is a tad obscure at points (hence coming here for questions :). If you'd like to offer a cross platform alternative, I'm happy for any suggestion.

Comment: I haven't used it, but Appcelerator Titanium looks like a decent solution for writing cross platform apps with web technology.  Personally, I would go with a more traditional, and better supported toolkit and wouldn't touch XUL unless I absolutely had to.  WxPython  + WxGlade would be my first choice for rapid development, but there are plenty of other options.

Comment: @mikerobi. I've also been playing with Titanium for a while. It's an ok solution. The debug is terrible and it can't seem to be able to generate a standalone distributable app, the final output - on PC at least - is an installer, which isn't what I want. 
Thanks for the WxPython + WxGlade suggestion, i'll check it out (maybe it's time I learn python :)

Comment: @mikerobi. Is it possible to compile a wxPython app into a stand-alone native app for PC or MAC?
(which was sort of one of my primary requirements)

Comment: Yes, with py2exe, cx_freeze, or py2app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did some more research on the XULRunner subject and since I have some finding, I'll just answer my own question in case someone comes here hoping for an answer.

The answer is the **Mozilla Build System**

The most advanced tutorial on the subject that I could find is:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Creating_XULRunner_Apps_with_the_Mozilla_Build_System

Thank you very kindly to its author for attempting to make a tutorial on the subject.

A lot of questions can be answered in the Mozilla dev builds forum:

http://groups.google.com/group/mozilla.dev.builds/topics

I found those resources helpfull, hope these help someone too.

**EDIT**:

There is also a simpler way of doing it without have to use the MBS, 
[as described here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XULRunner/Deploying_XULRunner_1.8) (works with 1.9 even if the doc is 1.8 centric)

Another approach is to look at [XULExplorer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL_Explorer), take it appart and build one from it as a base.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I have created an application similar to Songbird at my previous job. It is used for lecture capturing. It builds upon GStreamer through an XPCOM component. The way how the view is displayed on top of a XUL window is very similar to Songbird's approach.

Now I must tell you that working with XULRunner can be painful at times. Especially if you are also making an XPCOM plugin.

Concerning deployment, on Mac you can create an application bundle using these commands (assuming your application folder is called "hello"):

```
xulrunner-bin --install-app hello .
mkdir hello.app/Contents/Frameworks
# Copy the XUL Framework in the application bundle:
svn export XUL.Framework hello.app/Contents/Frameworks/XUL.Framework
```

On Windows I used NSIS to create an installer that bundles the XULRunner runtime together with the application. It creates a shortcut to xulrunner.exe that has the application.ini file as command line parameter.

**Edit**
You may also want to check out the [Qt Declarative UI](http://labs.trolltech.com/page/Projects/Graphics/Kinetic/DeclarativeUI) library. I haven't used it, but I would like to :)