# Do XUL applications work only on Firefox

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, xul

I've seen an XUL-based application recently that supposedly works on the desktop. Isn't XUL the Firefox language? I thought it wouldn't work on anything other that Firefox and certainly wouldn't work as a desktop application.

Can someone who knows more about XUL confirm its compatibility with other browsers (IE, Chrome, etc.) and if it runs as a desktop application, its compatibility with operating systems (Windows, Mac, Linux)

Answer (score 1):

check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XULRunner.  it was created to run xul applications like firefox. [songbird](http://www.getsongbird.com/) is also based in XUL.  for more detail see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384274/building-xul-app-a-la-songbird).

to actually answer the real question, yes, desktop apps can be built in xul, as firefox is.  the wiki page i linked to even points to a video game being built using it.  at its core its just another application framework.

Answer (score 1):

[XUL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/xul) is a descriptive language for UI used in Firefox **but** also used in other mozilla apps, like Thunderbird for example

There is a projet named [Xul Runner](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XULRunner) which allow using XUL for desktop apps (see [Pencil](http://pencil.evolus.vn/en-US/Home.aspx) for example).

AFAIK, all Mozilla apps are compatible with Windows, Mac, Linux and other system for some.

Answer (score 1):

[XUL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/xul) is a user interface language. It was created originally for mozilla/firefox, but is also used by [thunderbird](http://www.mozillamessaging.com/thunderbird/).

The [Gecko](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko) layout engine is what renders XUL and any application that uses this engine can be built with it. See [XUL Runner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XULRunner).

The layout engine has been written with cross platform concerns, so it runs on Windows, Linux and Macs.

Comment: i don't think gecko does xul layout anymore.  i think xulrunner replaced it for rendering xul, but gecko is still used for web browser rendering.

Comment: @nathan gonzalez - See my [Gecko](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko) link: `In XUL-based applications Gecko is used to render the application's user interface`

Answer (score 1):

XUL only works on xulrunner, and Firefox is built on top of xulrunner.  Other applications are built on xulrunner (e.g. Thunderbird).  You can also build applications on top of xulrunner.